# How do I convert well log measured depth to feet in Ocean for Petrel?

Tags: c#, ocean, petrel, unit-conversion

I want to export a well log from a `Slb.Ocean.Petrel.DomainObject.Well.WellLog` to an external file, but the the measured depth I get is in meters even if the project is set up to use feet.

I can convert the well log samples with the converter I get from:

```
var converter = PetrelUnitSystem.GetConverterToUI(wellLog.WellLogVersion.UnitMeasurement);
```

How do I get a converter for the measured depth?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hallgrim,

You can get a converter from the invariant Ocean unit to the Petrel display unit:

```
IUnitConverter convertToDisplayMD = PetrelUnitSystem.GetConverterToUI(Domain.MD);
```

Here is an example using it:

```
double valueToConvert = 3;

IUnit displayMD = PetrelUnitSystem.GetDisplayUnit(Domain.MD.Template);
IUnit oceanMD = PetrelUnitSystem.GetInvariantUnit(Domain.MD.Template);

PetrelLogger.InfoOutputWindow("converting " + valueToConvert.ToString() + 
" from: the Ocean unit for measured depth " + oceanMD.Symbol + 
" to: " + displayMD.Symbol + " = " + convertToDisplayMD.Convert(valueToConvert));
```

The output in the Petrel Message log will be:

> "converting 3 from: the Ocean unit for measured depth m to: ft =
>   9.84251968503937"

, for a project having measured depth in feet.